# Is buying older power plants than what you have disallowed?

Tags: house-rules, power-grid

In a recent game of Power Grid, someone we play with regularly insisted on a rule that you're not allowed to purchase a "lower" technology power plant than you already have.  e.g. if you have 13,17,25 as your power plants, you can't buy 24 or lower if they come up.

He also insisted that if a player didn't win their power plant auction that the market isn't refreshed before they got another chance to bid.  e.g. Player A bids cost, player B bids cost + 1 and player A decides not to bid higher.  In this scenario player A only gets to choose from the 3 remaining plants next.

The question: are these official rules?  I have scanned the rule book and didn't see either, but may have missed them... I also found them quite hard to work with.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> someone we play with regularly insisted on a rule that you're not allowed to purchase a "lower" technology power plant than you already have. e.g. if you have 13,17,25 as your power plants, you can't buy 24 or lower if they come up.

Incorrect.  You can buy any power plant that is in the market (the lowest four numbered plants).

> if a player didn't win their power plant auction that the market isn't refreshed before they got another chance to bid.

Incorrect.  After any power plant is purchased or destroyed, the market is immediately refreshed and realigned.

http://riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_5_gameRules.pdf

Page 3, section 2b (this is retyped and not copy-pasted, so there may be typos)

> The player chooses one power plant from the actual market (top row) and then makes a bid to purchase it.  [...] He pays his highest bid to the bank and takes the power plant.  Players then immediately draw a new card to replace the card sold and place the new card in the market.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.  I didn't think they were "real" rules but before I argue the toss next time wanted to get an answer from someone more familiar than I.